# DjangoAdmin: User model without changelist

Tags: django, django-admin, changelist

I will have many users on my app, so it's better not showing them on changelist at the beginning.
They're gonna be showed only after searching for them.
So, how to not show the changelist on Django Admin? I tried list_max_show_all=0 , but it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: Try changing the admin template for changelists as mentioned here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#set-up-your-projects-admin-template-directories

Comment: Thanks arocks! It should work ;)